# How to set the state based on the local storage without overwriting it with the initial state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I try to get the updated `localstorage` state called `darkmode` with `useContext` but when I console log it in functions inside `App.tsx` it gives the default value set inside `Context.js` :

App.tsx:

```js
const { darkmode } = useContext(Context);

React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(darkmode);
}, []);
```

Context.js:

```js
import { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";

const Context = createContext();

function ContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [darkmode, setDarkmode] = useState(false);

  // Local Storage: setting & getting data
  useEffect(() => {
    const darkmode = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("darkmode"));
    if (darkmode) {
      setDarkmode(darkmode);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("darkmode", JSON.stringify(darkmode));
  }, [darkmode]);

  const toggleDarkmode = () => {
    setDarkmode((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        darkmode,
        toggleDarkmode,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

export { ContextProvider, Context };
```

Local storage:

[image: localstorage]

The console logs:

[image: console]

How can I get the latest updated `localstorage` state with react context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issue

The problem is caused by the below `useEffect` and how you are initially setting the state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("darkmode", JSON.stringify(darkmode));
}, [darkmode]);
```

The above `useEffect` runs every time `darkmode` changes, but also on mount. And on mount, `darkmode` is equal to `false`, the value given to `useState`. So the `localStorage` is set to `false`, overwriting anything previously registered.

## Solution

A solution is to change how you are setting the state, so you pick what's in the `localStroge` if there is something:

```
const [darkmode, setDarkmode] = useState(!localStorage.getItem("darkmode") ? false : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("darkmode")));
```

## Beyond

Or, in case you don't wanna access to the local storage in `useState`, which can cause issues for frameworks that render both on the client and server, like Next.js, you can change your `useEffect` with one additional state:

```
const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
    // This allows the `useEffect` that fetches data from local storage to run first:
    if(firstRender){
      setFirstRender(false);
      return;
    }
    localStorage.setItem("darkmode", JSON.stringify(darkmode));
}, [darkmode, firstRender]);
```

## Aside

Also, to log `darkmode` changes, consider adding it to the dependency array of `useEffect`:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(darkmode);
}, [darkmode]);
```